# Selenium java: How to fail test if element not present?

Tags: selenium, cucumber

Starting with Selenium/Cucumber, I want to check the presence of an element on my application (h1 title).
For this I drew inspiration from the following code when writing this method:

```
@Then("the admin arrives on the clients/prospects dashboard")
    public boolean the_admin_arrives_on_the_clients_prospects_dashboard() {
        return driver.findElements(By.xpath("//h1[contains(text(), 'Dashboard')]")).size() != 0;
    }
```

However, I would like my test to fail if the element is not present. Is the fact that the method returns the "false" value enough to make the test fail? Many thanks

Comment: Are you also using TestNG in your project ?

Answer (score 1):

`list.size() != 0` returning ***false*** indicates the *list* doesn't contain any elements.

That definately validates the element is **not** present.

Comment: A method returning `false` doesn't fail a test, which is what OP is asking for.

Comment: @JeffC Reread OP's comment. That would clear all your doubts.

Comment: `Is the fact that the method returns the "false" value enough to make the test fail?` The answer to that question is no but you've answered yes.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Michael Mintz, here's how you do asserts in Cucumber.

NOTE: You need to import `Junit.Assert` in your Step Definition file.

```
@Then("the admin arrives on the clients/prospects dashboard")
public boolean the_admin_arrives_on_the_clients_prospects_dashboard() {
    assertFalse(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//h1[contains(text(), 'Dashboard')]")).size() != 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check use isEmpty() method for your check:

```
public boolean isElementPresented(final By locator) {
    return webDriver.findElements(locator).isEmpty();
}
```